# Apply custom css class or id using executeCommand

Tags: jquery, css

I want to build custom wysiwyg, just like stackoverflow wysiwyg with code tag. I create code button to apply css style written into css class `mycode` and I want to apply using executeCommand to on button click. I try, but it did not work.

css code

```
.mycode{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

javascript code

```
function iFrameOn(){
   richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
}  

function iCode(){
   richTextField.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", 0, false);
   richTextField.document.execCommand(".mycode", 0, true);
}
```

and HTML code

```
<body onLoad="iFrameOn();">        
  <input type="button" onClick="iCode()" value="Code">
<textarea style="display:none;" name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
</body>
```

any suggestion how can I apply custom css class using `executecommand()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do: you want to apply a custom CSS on the click of a button.

If that is the case you have to import your CSS in a slightly different way:

CSS: you can see the CSS that is applied at the start is done as normal and those that I don't want to change I use the `@import url`

```
<!--
    stylesheet
-->
<style type="text/css">@import url("stylesheets/default.css");</style> 
<style type="text/css">@import url("stylesheets/social.css");</style> 
<!-- cube style to allow CSS change -->
<style type="text/css">@import url("stylesheets/default-cube.css");</style> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/blackandwhite.css" />
```

Then when I want to load a different CSS file I change the `attr`

jQuery

```
$('#changeco').click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "stylesheets/colour.css");
    return false;
});
```

For a working example please see, click the colour/black and white boxes.

http://portfolio.chrisloughnane.net/

jsfiddle does not like hard coding imports so I just inc. the above link.